# Correlation coefficient as a dependent variable in regression analysis

Tags: regression, correlation, dependent-variable

Since my knowledge of statistics is less than perfect I decided to ask if my research methodology is acceptable.

Is it possible to use a correlation coefficient as a dependent variable in a regression analysis?

I have correlation coefficients for social status and life satisfaction for a set of countries. What I'm trying to do is to see if other variables like the Gini coefficient for the countries can predict the relationship between status and LS.

Comment: It is mathematically possible.  For it to be statistically meaningful you would likely (a) need to recognize that you *don't* have the actual correlation coefficients--you only have estimates, whose uncertainties you should accommodate in the analysis; and (b) need to re-express the correlations, perhaps using Fisher's Z transformation. Then there is the substantive issue: is this *really* an appropriate analysis for the scientific questions you have?  Could you articulate those questions in some clear, meaningful way that is more specific than "predict the relationship"?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Cross Validated!

I understand that you're trying to see if variables like Gini coefficient of a country can predict/affect the relationship between social status and life satisfaction of that country. What you're proposing is pretty unusual, and I think you'd run into some logical/logistical/data issues.

I'm not sure what your overall objective is (maybe you could explain that more in your question, and I can adjust my answer), but I think what would accomplish your goal is just *including* Gini coefficient in your regression of social status vs. life satisfaction. This way, the regression will control for both, and you will see the relationship between status vs. life satisfaction *given* the Gini coefficient.